# Comparing log in times of faculty and remarks will either be Present, Late or Absent

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, worksheet-function

[image: Excel file screenshot here]

I am using Excel 2016 to manage our faculty attendance.

Last year, I was fine putting in the times manually, but I want to automate some aspects of this Excel file.

Which leads to my question: How can I compare the login time per class of the teacher and have its corresponding remark (Present, Late, or Absent)

I am working with 2 different worksheets btw.

Tried using VLOOKUP, INDEX, and even ISNA.

Comment: So test for x minutes past the hour, if less then present, if more then late and no value is absent. Many examples of the use of if() exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample worksheet (input data basis class time) as in the image. I am assuming, you can get all your class data in a single table-

[image]

I have already shown the solution in the right part of image. Say you have two columns - Actual class timing, and the actual log-in time of faculty.

You can use Vlookup with range and filters -

1. [Filter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) : This will filter the vlook-up data basis the original class time
2. Range look-up : In the vlookup, the last parameter '['range-lookup']- make it 1 to search between ranges. Your login time should be a 'time' value not a string. If it is a string, convert it to time

In the image above formulae in cell I2 is `=VLOOKUP($H2, FILTER($B$2:$C$39, $A$2:$A$39=$G2),2,1)`

**Edit**

I have put the lookup table in a different excel `Book2`, and changed the formula for that -

[image]

The new formula for Cell I2 is `=VLOOKUP($H2, FILTER([Book2]Sheet1!$B$2:$C$39,[Book2]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$39=$G2),2,1)`

Comment: Not the same worksheet actually. I still need to reference the sheet where the range is whether Present, Late, or Absent

Comment: So just change those references in Filter formula

Comment: It keeps on saying the function is invalid.

Comment: Please see the edits -  I have used lookup data from a different table

Comment: I've tried your formula but it still says invalid. I even used $ signs and yet it still is invalid

Comment: You need to edit the formula with your ranges and worksheet names. That's all I can say